# Download video in mobile and play it using flex mobile project

Tags: android, apache-flex, video, directory, documents

I am downloading a video from internet to a mobile device and want to play it. I am unable to get the right path of that video. I don't know video will save in desktopDirectory or documentsDirectory.

I have an array that contains names of each video. Any idea how to get the path and play it in videoDisplay?

For mobile devices, VideoDisplay is not recommended. Is there any other player to run videos on mobile device?

My code is

```
fr = new FileReference(); 
request = new URLRequest(file_url);
fr.download(request);
trace("Downloading "+request);

fr.addEventListener(Event.OPEN,start);                  fr.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,updateProgress);
fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,complete);

private function complete(event:Event):void {
      progress_indicator.visible = false;
      progress_label.text =  "100% completed";
    trace("File: "+fr.name);
    var appmanager:ApplicationManager = ApplicationManager.SharedApplicationManager();
    appmanager.DownloadedVideos[appmanager.DownloadedVideos.length] = fr.name;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code imran ?

Comment: please check my updated code above

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope you're using Flex for more than just playing a video as that would be very inefficient.  Second, you should be using [StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html) to play videos on mobile devices since it's hardware accelerated. You should look at the some of the [tutorials from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html) on how to use it on devices.